# How does adding a variable as a property affect it?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

What difference does it make in memory management to define a variable as a property? For instance:

```
@interface foo {
  NSString *theStr;
}
@end

@implementation foo
- (void)bar {
  NSLog(theStr);
}
@end
```

Versus:

```
@interface foo {
  NSString *theStr;
}
@property(retain) NSString *theStr;
@end

@implementation foo
@synthesize theStr;
- (void)bar {
  NSLog(theStr);
}
@end
```

It seems like the first is autoreleased or something similar, while the second is retained throughout the life of the class. Is that the case, or what is the difference?

Comment: Your example doesn't really make sense the way it is written; you aren't synthesizing the correct thing nor do you **set** the value of the variable in either version, which is where memory management is relevant.

Comment: You should be aware that `NSLog` should always have a literal format string as its first argument.

Comment: I left out the setting of the variable because my question partly revolved around that, so I wasn't sure the correct way to go about it.

Comment: Absolutely @JoshCaswell, thanks, I should have used a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a variable just in the interface without defining it as a property (as in your first example) means that you'll have to take care of everything related to memory management yourself. Assigning something to that variable will not retain it automatically, not will setting the variable to something else release the previous value.

Defining it as a property creates getter and setter methods under the hood. Most importantly, if you use it with the "retain" keyword, your setter method will retain the new value (and release the old one if there was one).

Note that the setter method will only be invoked if you use the dot notation, e.g., `self.myStr = @"new string"`, or the method call, e.g., `[self setMyStr:@"new string"]`. If you just call `myStr = @"new string"` the setter method will not be called and you need to release the old value yourself and retain the new one.

Comment: As a follow up: when it is not defined as a property and managed by Interface Builder, do I need to worry about its memory management or does IB take care of it?

Comment: In that case it wouldn't be retained, so you need to worry about memory management. Usually you'd want it as a property unless you have the superview as a property already, since a superview already retains all of it's subviews. Have a look at this: http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=95

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the first case shows an autoreleased object, it would all depend on how you managed the creation and the destruction of that particular object. If for instance when you create that object you call:

```
//This string will indeed be autoreleased
theStr=[NSString stringWithString:@"Jibber jabber"];

//Or even
theStr=@"Jibber jabber";
```

But you have to take charge of the memory management if you create it in the following way:

```
//Manage my memory
theStr=[[NSString alloc] init];

//You have to release this property on the dealloc method
-(void)dealloc{
    [theStr release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

On your second example, you create a setter and a getter method for the property `theStr` and by adding the `nonatomic` attribute, you make your property not thread safety, meaning that a thread can begin to modify your property while another one is already editing it. And by setting the `retain` attribute to your property, the setter method will be synthesized the following way:

```
- (void) setTheStr:(NSString *) newString {
    [newString retain]; 
    [theStr release]; 
    theStr = newSupervisor; 
}
```

You can consult more about this in one of my favorite books, [Learning Objective-C 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321711386) in chapter 12.

Comment: Another great answer, I appreciate it!